# Detectar distinção entre o model escolhido pelo usuário para cadastro

Tags: django, django-2.0

Olá, então, criei alguns models para cadastro de usuários no django 2.0 e agora estou precisando saber qual deles o usuário optou por se cadastrar. Como podem ver tenho o model pessoa física (CustomUserN), pessoa jurídica (CustomCompany) e o model admin (CustomUser), fiz um template para o usuário escolher entre esses dois:

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-4"></div>
     <div class="col-5">
        <h2>Como deseja se cadastrar? </h2>
     </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <a href="{% url 'register' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Pessoa física   <i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-2"> <a href="{% url 'registercom' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Pessoa jurídica   <i class="fas fa-building"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

E que redireciona para essas duas funções:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'register-sucess.html', {'user': user})
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})

def registercom(request):
    form = CustomCompanyCreationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        user.set_password(user.password)
        form.save()
        return render(request, 'register-sucess.html', {'user': user})
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Como faço para criar um algoritmo que eu consiga detectar essa diferença, sendo que são models diferentes, por exemplo para que eu consiga realizar diferentes edições de perfil com os devidos campos?

```
#TODO: MODEL ADMIN E PAI DOS DEMAIS MODELS DE LOGIN
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('E-mail '), max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('Nome de usuário '), max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.CharField(_('Data de início '), max_length=20, default=timezone.now())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Usuário')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Usuários')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

#TODO: MODEL DE PESSOA JURÍDICA, SEM VALIDADOR PARA CPNPJ/TELEFONE/CEP
class CustomCompany(CustomUser):
    name = models.CharField(_('Razão social '), max_length= 30, default=' ')
    UF_CHOICES = (
        ('ac','AC'),
        ('al','AL'),
        ('ap','AP'),
        ('am','AM'),
        ('ba','BA'),
        ('ce','CE'),
        ('df','DF'),
        ('es','ES'),
        ('go','GO'),
        ('ma','MA'),
        ('mt','MT'),
        ('ms','MS'),
        ('mg','MG'),
        ('pa','PA'),
        ('pb','PB'),
        ('pr','PR'),
        ('pe','PE'),
        ('pi','PI'),
        ('rj','RJ'),
        ('rn','RN'),
        ('rs','RS'),
        ('ro','RO'),
        ('rr','RR'),
        ('sc','SC'),
        ('sp','SP'),
        ('se','SE'),
        ('to','TO'),

    )
    DEP_CHOICES = (
        ('lab', 'Laboratório Protético'),
        ('clin', 'Clínica Odontológica'),
        ('out', 'Outro tipo'),
    )
    departamento = models.CharField(_('Estabelecimento '), max_length=10, choices=DEP_CHOICES, default='clin')
    cnpj = models.CharField(_('CNPJ(somente números) '), max_length=12, unique=True, default=' ')
    telefone = models.CharField(_('Telefone '), max_length=12, default=' ')
    cep = models.CharField(_('CEP '), max_length=10, default=' ')
    endereco = models.CharField(_('Endereço '), max_length=30, default=' ')
    cidade = models.CharField(_('Cidade '), max_length=20, default=' ')
    uf = models.CharField(_('UF '), max_length=2, choices=UF_CHOICES, default='sp')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'departamento', 'cnpj', 'telefone', 'cep', 'endereco', 'cidade', 'uf']
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cadastro jurídico'
        verbose_name_plural = "Cadastros jurídicos"

    def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            CustomCompany.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()

#TODO: MODEL DE PESSOA FÍSICA, SEM VALIDADOR PARA CPF/TELEFONE/CEP
class CustomUserN(CustomUser):
    name = models.CharField(_('Nome completo '), max_length=30, default=' ')
    USER_CHOICES = (
        ('dentista', 'Dentista'),
        ('protetico', 'Protético'),
        ('outra','Outra'),
    )
    UF_CHOICES = (
        ('ac', 'AC'),
        ('al', 'AL'),
        ('ap', 'AP'),
        ('am', 'AM'),
        ('ba', 'BA'),
        ('ce', 'CE'),
        ('df', 'DF'),
        ('es', 'ES'),
        ('go', 'GO'),
        ('ma', 'MA'),
        ('mt', 'MT'),
        ('ms', 'MS'),
        ('mg', 'MG'),
        ('pa', 'PA'),
        ('pb', 'PB'),
        ('pr', 'PR'),
        ('pe', 'PE'),
        ('pi', 'PI'),
        ('rj', 'RJ'),
        ('rn', 'RN'),
        ('rs', 'RS'),
        ('ro', 'RO'),
        ('rr', 'RR'),
        ('sc', 'SC'),
        ('sp', 'SP'),
        ('se', 'SE'),
        ('to', 'TO'),

    )
    tipo = models.CharField(_('Profissão '), max_length=10, choices=USER_CHOICES, default='dentista')
    cpf = models.CharField(_('CPF(somente números) '), max_length=12, unique=True, default=' ')
    cro = models.CharField(_('CRO(somente números) '), max_length=25, unique=True, default=' ')
    Empresa_para_qual_trabalha = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    telefone = models.CharField(_('Telefone '), max_length=12, default=' ')
    foto = models.ImageField(upload_to='fotos_usuarios', null=True, blank=True)
    cep = models.CharField(_('CEP '), max_length=10, default=' ')
    endereco = models.CharField(_('Endereço '), max_length=30, default=' ')
    cidade = models.CharField(_('Cidade '), max_length=20, default=' ')
    uf = models.CharField(_('UF '), max_length=2, choices=UF_CHOICES, default='sp')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'tipo', 'cpf', 'cro', 'Empresa_para_qual_trabalha', 'telefone','foto', 'cep', 'endereco', 'cidade', 'uf']
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Cadastro físico'
        verbose_name_plural = "Cadastros físicos"

    def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            CustomUserN.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: Não entendi sua questão. Mas olhando seu modelo, o correto é você criar um model `Pessoa` com as informações que são iguais em fisica e juridica, e outros dois models `PessoaFisica(Pessoa)` e `PessoaJuridica(Pessoa)` herdando as informações de `Pessoa`.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, sendo CustomUser para cadastro do admin, herdando dele CustomUserN para fisica e CustomCompany para juridica, não adicionei os dados comuns pelo fato de dificultar o cadastramento do superuser que seria o model pai dos outros dois. Mas o que quis dizer foi que cada model é direcionado segundo a opção dada pelo usuário através de buttons, porém preciso detectar qual desses foi escolhido pelo usuário, pensei em salvar uma variável com uma numeração que indique que tipo de model foi salvo, porém não sei bem onde a colocar e como fazer isso. Tem alguma dica?